# “Get to know” usage

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

Can I use this phrase for complete strangers?

For example, my friend and I are sitting at the table in a coffee shop. There is a girl sitting at another table. I want **to come to her, introduce myself and have a conversation with her**.
To share my thoughts with the friend, I should say:

1. I want **to meet her**. – As I think, the word “meet” doesn’t fit since I've already met her, even if we don’t know each other.
2. I want **to pick her up**. – If there is not a girl, but a guy, and I want to just make a new friend? “Pick up” also doesn’t fit. Also, it's not very polite, is it?
3. I want **to get to know her**. – Can I use "get to know" here? I mean, if I already know someone, I can say: “I want to get to know her/him better”. But, if I don’t know that person at all, is it OK to use “get to know”?

If “get to know” is a bad choice, what should I put in the blank below?

– I want to **…** him/her.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the girl is sitting at another table, you want to meet her or to be introduced to her. The fact that you have seen her does not signify that you have met her, as you suggest.

**To get to know someone** is not the same as meeting them. It is only after you have met someone - or seen/heard (about) them - and presumably been attracted to them that you wish to take the relationship further by getting to know them (better).

You do NOT want to **pick her up**. This expression is used in two contexts and can easily be ambiguous. The first context is merely **to fetch** as in **to pick up your children from school** or **to pick up at parcel at the post office**. The second context is to secure the services of a prostitute, particularly a street walker.

In short, you want to meet the girl. The word **meet** exactly fits the context.